# SpringBootTest + JPA + Kafka - context is not loading properly during testing

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

I have Spring Boot application with kafka and jpa in it. I am using h2 as my in-memory database. For each test class execution, I don't want kafka to come up for each test class. I have 2 test classes, one is KafkaConsumerTest and another one is JPATest. KafkaConsumerTest is annotated with @SpringBootTest and it perfectly loads the entire application and passes all the test. However, for JPATest, I don't want to bring up the entire application and just few desired context to test out JPA related changes. When I do that, it is throwing the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:958)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:138)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:172)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:233)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:815)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:256)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:769)
```

I am passing the datasource with jdbcUrl in my application.yml file

src/test/resources/application.yml

```
spring:
   datasource:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
      driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
      username: sa
   kafka:
     bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

KafkaConsumerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest (classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
                topics = {"${kafka.topic}"})
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
```

JpaTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, classes = {JPAConfiguration.class})
public class NotificationServiceTest {
```

I tried putting loader as AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class but it gave me the same error. I tried specifying application.yml exclusively using TestPropertyResource but still the same error.

```
@TestPropertyResource(locations = {"classpath:application.yml"})
```

I think I am not able to load the context properly here and application.yml file is not able to pick or parse values here.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue. The reason of this issue was spring context was not getting loaded properly for other tests as I was not using @SpringBootTest. How I bypassed the error and also loading the spring boot context only for one time was to create a base class like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
        topics = {"${kafka.topic}"})
public abstract class AbstractSpringBootTest {
}
```

Now every test class has to extend this class as per the following code. This way spring test will be loaded once only provided the context doesn't get changed during the tests run.

```
public class MyTest  extends AbstractSpringBootTest {
```

Posting the solution which worked for me for other people's reference.